# How can I filter out problems in VS Code based on text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code 1.41.0 on Windows 10 x64.

In my code (which is in a research language you've likely never heard of), there is a certain class of warning message I get a lot of in the Problems panel, and I want to ignore those messages. The text of the message varies a bit across instances, but it always contains the word "duplicate". How can I filter **out** problems containing "duplicate"? The text filter that already exists **keeps** problems containing the specified text, and I want the opposite.

I tried `!duplicate` but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versions of VS Code prior to the March 2021 release were not able to do negative text content filters using the `!` prefix- only negative glob (file path) filters. This was tracked in [Support negative filters on text
#62531](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62531), which was implemented for said release in [fix #62531 add negative text filtering to Problems #115351](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/115351).

From my quick test on version 1.82.1, some syntax which is typically used in file globs such as `{foo,bar}` does not work for negative text *content* filtering. If you want such a feature, you can raise an issue ticket asking for it.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score 4):

Not the answer you are looking for, but negative filters currently only work with glob patterns, not with text. This is a known issue with the filter feature of the problem panel in vscode. You can check the progress here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62531

Comment: Note: Negative filtering is being added to v1.55 for text.  The 62531 fix has been merged.